# Calculate winning or losing streak of players in Python DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with all the tennis matches played from a few years.

The dataframe is named `tennis_data_processed`. I am gonna show it filtered for a few matches of a specific player (10000). The variable `target` refers to if player1 won (1) or player1 lost (0).

| tourney_date | player1_id | player2_id | target |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-10-31 | 100000 | 209950 | 0 |
| 2023-02-06 | 123456 | 100000 | 0 |
| 2023-02-06 | 100000 | 543210 | 1 |
| 2023-02-06 | 100000 | 876543 | 1 |
| 2023-02-06 | 345612 | 100000 | 1 |
| 2023-02-20 | 432154 | 100000 | 1 |
| 2023-02-20 | 100000 | 929292 | 0 |

The goal is to add two new features, `player1_streak` and `player2_streak`, showing the streak the player is on.

The first match that appears in the dataframe for that player should have a value of 0. From there, if the first match is won, we would add 1 to the streak, if he wins again we would show it as 2. If he loses this match, then the streak would be shown as -1, if he loses again, -2, and so on. If he wins again then the streak would be shown as 1 again. This should be done for both player1 and player2.

We should take into account that the current `player1_id` in a given row, might appear either in the `player1_id` or `player2_id` column.

An example of the resulting table following the table given above:

| tourney_date | player1_id | player2_id | target | player1_streak | player2_streak |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-10-31 | 100000 | 209950 | 0 | 0 | X |
| 2023-02-06 | 123456 | 100000 | 0 | X | -1 |
| 2023-02-06 | 100000 | 543210 | 1 | 1 | X |
| 2023-02-06 | 100000 | 876543 | 1 | 2 | X |
| 2023-02-06 | 345612 | 100000 | 1 | X | 3 |
| 2023-02-20 | 432154 | 100000 | 1 | X | -1 |
| 2023-02-20 | 100000 | 929292 | 0 | -2 | X |

This should be done for `player1_id` and for `player2_id`.

A dictionary of the table used at the beggining for help:

```python
tennis_data_processed = {
    'tourney_date': ['2022-10-31', '2023-02-06', '2023-02-06', '2023-02-06', '2023-02-06', '2023-02-20', '2023-02-20'],
    'player1_id': [100000, 123456, 100000, 100000, 345612, 432154, 100000],
    'player2_id': [209950, 100000, 543210, 876543, 100000, 100000, 929292],
    'target': [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With pure Python :

```
# For convenience: df instead of tennis_data_processed

cnt = dict.fromkeys(np.unique(df.filter(like="player")), 0)

streaks = []
for p1, p2, t in df[["player1_id", "player2_id", "target"]].to_numpy():
    streaks.append([cnt[p1], cnt[p2]])
    cnt[p1] = max(cnt[p1] + 1 - t, +1)
    cnt[p2] = min(cnt[p2] - 1 + t, -1)

out = df.join(pd.DataFrame(streaks, columns=["player1_streak", "player2_streak"]))
```

Output :

```
  tourney_date  player1_id  player2_id  target  player1_streak  player2_streak
0   2022-10-31      100000      209950       0               0               0
1   2023-02-06      123456      100000       0               0              -1
2   2023-02-06      100000      543210       1               1               0
3   2023-02-06      100000      876543       1               2               0
4   2023-02-06      345612      100000       1               0               3
5   2023-02-20      432154      100000       1               0              -1
6   2023-02-20      100000      929292       0              -2               0
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this, you can create a Python function that calculates the streaks for both players based on the given conditions. Then, apply this function to each row of the DataFrame.

```
import pandas as pd

# Create the DataFrame
tennis_data_processed = {
    'tourney_date': ['2022-10-31', '2023-02-06', '2023-02-06', '2023-02-06', '2023-02-06', '2023-02-20', '2023-02-20'],
    'player1_id': [100000, 123456, 100000, 100000, 100000, 345612, 432154],
    'player2_id': [209950, 100000, 543210, 876543, 100000, 100000, 929292],
    'target': [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0]
}

tennis_data_processed_df = pd.DataFrame(tennis_data_processed)

def calculate_streaks(df):
    player1_streak = 0
    player2_streak = 0
    player1_streaks = []
    player2_streaks = []

    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        player1_id = row['player1_id']
        player2_id = row['player2_id']
        target = row['target']

        if target == 1:
            player1_streak += 1
            player2_streak = 0
        else:
            player2_streak += 1
            player1_streak = 0

        player1_streaks.append(player1_streak)
        player2_streaks.append(player2_streak)

    df['player1_streak'] = player1_streaks
    df['player2_streak'] = player2_streaks

calculate_streaks(tennis_data_processed_df)

# Display the resulting DataFrame
print(tennis_data_processed_df)
```